# How to FILTER based on a secondary, or even tertiary, FILTER?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet as follows:

I need to get a count of how many upsells were bought when a specific product was their main purchase.

For example, product A should return 2 (orders 102, and 108).

```
Order ID    Date          Type         Customer ID    Product
100         2019-01-10    Main         21             A
102         2019-01-10    Upsell       21             B
104         2019-01-10    Main         22             A
106         2019-01-10    Main         23             A
108         2019-01-11    Upsell       23             C
110         2019-01-11    Main         24             A   
...         ...           ...          ...            ...
```

---

Right now I'm using an annoyingly complicated `FILTER` in a cell akin to this:

`=COUNTA(FILTER(A:A, C:C = "Upsell", D:D = FILTER(D:D, C:C = "Main", E:E = "A")))`

However this doesn't seem to work. It also wouldn't exactly do what is needed. Technically if someone also later bought any other product than product A as their main purchase, any of their upsells would still count while searching for the number of upsells from product A.

Is there an easier/more reliable way to do this?

Is it possible to setup a loop in Google Apps Scripts that can do this? (Loop through every matching row, find all rows containing the same customer ID that are upsells within, say, 2 days after the main purchase or until their next main purchase?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try overlapping ranges:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A3:A8,D2:D7=D3:D8,C3:C8="Upsell",C2:C7="Main",E2:E7="A"))
```

Assuming A1:E7 has your table,

- `C2:C7="Main",E2:E7="A"` will be Product A Main filter
- `C3:C8="Upsell"` Is the next product a Upsell?
- `D2:D7=D3:D8` Is it the same customer that bought the upsell and the main?
- `FILTER` and `COUNT` the corresponding upsell order ids.